# Safari Web Inspector Showing Up In New Window By Default

Tags: safari, web-inspector

I've been using Chrome and am going back and forth between switching to Safari or staying with Chrome. My one small issue with Safari though is that the web inspector always shows up in a new window every time I toggle it. I press Command-Option-I and it opens in a new window and when I press Command-Option-I again it does not go away. I love the way the web inspector functions in Chrome and am wondering if there's a way to run the same way in Safari.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem with the new version of Safari

Comment: There is a defaults value which can be read by `defaults read com.apple.Safari WebKitInspectorAttached` but for me it says `1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug in the Safari codebase.

Here is the [bugreport](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65493) and they're working on it ([source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3191306?start=0&tstart=0))!

Comment: Thanks glad it's already in the process of getting fixed... I knew I wasn't going crazy.

Comment: This is fixed in the latest Webkit Nightly build: http://nightly.webkit.org/
Although now equally annoying it opens at 2/3rds the screen and doesn't remember your resized size. :(

Comment: The browser window width also has a bearing on this - make the window wider and close & re-open web inspector - this may fix it also

Comment: "they're working on it" – funny how this still happens in Safari 10.1.2

Comment: I have had the issue for a long time. Here is the solution.

Right-click on a web page and select inspect element.
The console window appears in Fullscreen. Minimize the window like any Safari web page and it should a window like below.
Just above the 'Elements' tab, you should be able to see 2 icons. Clicking the icon on the left, opens the Console in right side of the browser and clicking the icon on the right, opens the Console in bottom of the browser
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 25):

I have had the issue for a long time. Here is the solution.

1. Right-click on a web page and select inspect element.
2. The console window appears in Fullscreen. Minimize the window like any Safari web page and it should a window like below.
3. Just above the 'Elements' tab, you should be able to see 2 icons. Clicking the icon on the left, opens the Console in right side of the browser and clicking the icon on the right, opens the Console in bottom  of the browser

Hope this helps.

Comment: Blimey, that was driving me crazy. Thank you! Why they hide those buttons in full screen mode I do not know..

Comment: You saved my life.

Comment: clean and simple

Answer (score 11):

None of the methods upon are working for me (Safari 9.1), if you want to make the docking buttons of the inspector showing up:

- open Terminal
- type `defaults read com.apple.Safari "__WebInspectorPageGroupLevel1__.WebKit2InspectorStartsAttached"`

Once you checked if it returns 0,
do:
`defaults write com.apple.Safari "__WebInspectorPageGroupLevel1__.WebKit2InspectorStartsAttached" 1`

Answer (score 3):

You could press the *leftmost* button at the Inspector's status bar and Inspector will dock.

UPDATE: Now, the button is on the **right**. When Inspector is in a separate window, the two small buttons in its upper right corner make it move to the 1) bottom of the Safari window 2) right side of the Safari window.

Comment: Right, I can... and I have been every single time I open web inspector. It won't stay docked though. I close it and open it again and it's in a new window.

Answer (score 2):

The only method that seemed to work for me was to **resize** the browser to a big enough size that it was big enough to contain the **smallest** size of an individual Inspect window. This for me, was widening the browser to at least around 65% percent width of the screen, and then you can "Inspect Element" and the default would be that the Inspect window would be at the bottom of the browser, and the browser with the Inspect window in it is resizable to any size now. Hope this helps some people.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to fix safari issue

1. Go to Develop --> User Agent --> Safari --> Select iphone --> then click on right side top symbol...
2. Select it and do inspect then you can see the button on left side top corner.
3. Now set to default setting by redoing the first point.

[Please follow the step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YqfP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking as shown:

[image]

I hope you get as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I noticed when you have an open tab like the start page, the web inspector will pop up in a separate window. Also, there are no icons in the web inspector to attach it to the bottom or side. If you have a webpage open and do the same thing in the same window, that tab will have the web inspector attached to the bottom of the page (or whatever your attachment selection was prior).

Answer (score 0):

```
"com.apple.Safari.WebInspectorPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2InspectorStartsAttached" = 0;
```

the param/key/variable is

`"com.apple.Safari.WebInspectorPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2InspectorStartsAttached"`

so you would do the following in Terminal

```
~ % defaults read com.apple.Safari "com.apple.Safari.WebInspectorPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2InspectorStartsAttached"
```

FYI, someone made an erroneous reply above which lead me to look into it and got the correct information

they told you to do this ....

> ~ % defaults read com.apple.Safari
> "**WebInspectorPageGroupLevel1**.WebKit2InspectorStartsAttached"
> defaults[55436:4194341]  The domain/default pair of (/Users/*/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari,
> **WebInspectorPageGroupLevel1**.WebKit2InspectorStartsAttached) does not exist

[Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pagFA.png)